# RedShift: неожиданное округление значения после применения конструкции case when

Tags: postgresql, redshift

В RedShift пробую применить такую трансформацию (то есть для пустых значений проставить нули)

```
CASE
    WHEN s.files_duration != '' THEN s.files_duration
    ELSE 0.0 
END :: NUMERIC AS files_duration_2
```

Ожидаю, что для значений, которые содержат значения после точки, значения останутся без округления (как есть), но они почему-то округляются. Не могу понять почему.

Можете подсказать, что я делаю не так?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The default scale, if not specified, is 0." Укажите явно при описании NUMERIC(precision, scale) сколько нужно вам знаков после запятой. По умолчанию будет 0 знаков, если написать просто NUMERIC: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Numeric_types201.html

Comment: Спасибо. Так сработало, да